# Cannot open shared object file when using docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, hunspell

When I run the program following script:

```
from hunspell import Hunspell

if __name__ == '__main__':
    h = Hunspell()
    print(h.spell('test'))
```

On local machine everything is OK but when as soon as I build and run the code on docker, it throws following exception:

```
    from hunspell import Hunspell
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hunspell/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .hunspell import HunspellWrap as Hunspell
ImportError: libhunspell-1.3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My Dockerfile is something like:

```
FROM python:3

ADD main.py /

RUN pip install cyhunspell

CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]
```

[Hunspell](https://github.com/OpenGov/cython_hunspell) use c++ binary files that I think causing such exception.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue? Is it necessary to use Linux for base image in Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the missing packages:

```
FROM python:3

ADD main.py /
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libhunspell-1.3-0
RUN pip install cyhunspell

CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, although this code allowed me to build docker on my local but when I want to use in CL/CD pipeline I got into another problem could you please look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642368/ci-cd-pipeline-failed-e-unable-to-locate-package